# Determinants in Kerr-Schild via Sylvester theorem

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

The Kerr-Schild metric has the following form
\begin{align}
g_{\mu \nu} = \tilde{g}_{\mu \nu} + \kappa \phi l_{\mu} l_{\nu}
\end{align}
where $l^\mu l_\mu =0$. Here index are raised or lower by background metric $\tilde{g}$.

I know
\begin{align}
\det(g_{\mu \nu}) = \det(\tilde{g}_{\mu \nu})
\end{align}
And I want to prove this via Sylvester determinant theorem.

[Actually, I prove this relation via Taylor's trick of det trace properties. But I want to do using Sylvester's theorem to do more further generalization like extended Kerr Schild formalsim]

Sylvester's determinant identity :

Let $A$ and $B$ are the matrix of $m\times n$, $n\times m$ then
\begin{align}
\det(I_m + A B) = \det(I_n + BA)
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Taylor's trick", but this is just linear algebra: if $A$ is a matrix with rank $1$, then $$\det({\rm Id}+A)=1+{\rm tr}(A).$$Write $\widetilde{G} = (\widetilde{g}_{\mu\nu})$ and $G=(g_{\mu\nu})$. Then $$\det(G)=\det(\widetilde{G}+\kappa\phi\ell\ell^\top) = \det(\widetilde{G})\det({\rm Id}+\kappa\phi \widetilde{G}^{-1}\ell\ell^\top)=\det(\widetilde{G})(1+\kappa\phi \,{\rm tr}(\widetilde{G}^{-1}\ell\ell^\top)).$$But ${\rm tr}(\widetilde{G}^{-1}\ell\ell^\top)=\ell^\mu\ell_\mu=0$. Thus $\det(G)=\det(\widetilde{G})$.